# apache conditional statements - what is the processing order?

Tags: apache-2.4, conditional

I try to protect the access to a subdirectory by http auth using .htaccess file configuration.

This is the full working code for apache 2.4 in my case.

```
# Conditionally set environment variable BACKEND_PROTECTION (version for apache 2.4)

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.somedomain.de'">
    SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/typo3/" BACKEND_PROTECTION
</If>
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.someotherdomain.de'">
    SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/typo3/" BACKEND_PROTECTION
</If>

<RequireAny>
  <RequireAll>
    Require not env BACKEND_PROTECTION
    Require all granted
  </RequireAll>
  <RequireAll>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Protected URI"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/config/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </RequireAll>
</RequireAny>
```

Now I need to additionally exclude a subdirectory of that directory from authentification, so this is what I tried.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.somedomain.de'">
    SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/typo3/" BACKEND_PROTECTION
</If>
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.someotherdomain.de'">
    SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/typo3/" BACKEND_PROTECTION
</If>

# disable protection for backend files loaded in frontend
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/typo3/sysext/" !BACKEND_PROTECTION
```

But this does not work, after this code, the following `<RequireAny>` block from above triggers http authentification as if BACKEND_PROTECTION was stil set.
But if I put the negation inside `<If></If>` it works as expected.

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.somedomain.de'">
    SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/typo3/" BACKEND_PROTECTION
    SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/typo3/sysext/" !BACKEND_PROTECTION
</If>
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.someotherdomain.de'">
    SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/typo3/" BACKEND_PROTECTION
    SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "^/typo3/sysext/" !BACKEND_PROTECTION
</If>
```

Why is it that way? What does the following statement taken from the If-Documentation exactly mean?

> Description:  Contains directives that apply only if a condition is
>   satisfied by a request at runtime

Is the other code inside .htacces not processed during the same runtime? Or just in a earlier stage of that runtime during some kind of pre-compile step?